# convert timestamp with timezone to day of week

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, timezone

### table name: test

column name | datatype

order_date | timestamp w/ timezone (Eg: '2019-01-20 23:59:10+08')

looking to convert the timestamp to day of the week
example: 2019-01-20 = 'Sunday'

Comment: Local day of week, UTC day of week? and dbms?

Comment: assuming PostgreSQL and UTC

Comment: Possible cross-duplicate: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/135700/how-do-i-find-the-day-of-week-of-a-date-time-field-in-postgres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [EXTRACT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/functions-datetime.html) to extract the day of week as an integer and then convert it to a string:

```
SELECT
    CASE EXTRACT(DOW FROM order_date AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')
        WHEN 0 THEN 'Sunday'
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Monday'
        ...
    END
FROM test
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function which will return the day of week of a given date

```
create function day_of_week(@d as date) returns varchar(20)
as
begin
declare @day_of_week as varchar(20)
select @day_of_week =case datepart(w,getdate())
when 1 then 'Sunday'
when 2 then 'Monday'
when 3 then 'Tuesady'
when 4 then 'Wednasday'
when 5 then  'Thursday'
when 6 then  'Friday'
when 7 then 'Saturday'
end 
return @day_of_week
end
```